# Cloudflare's new .onion DNS resolver?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, dns, browsers, cloudflare

Cloudflare [recently announced](https://blog.cloudflare.com/welcome-hidden-resolver/) their new "hidden DNS resolver".

https://dns4torpnlfs2ifuz2s2yf3fc7rdmsbhm6rw75euj35pac6ap25zgqad.onion/

I'm wondering if it can be used with the tor browser or the tor binary for Debian/Ubuntu. Does it make sense to configure TBB to use this service?

Answer (score 1):

**Does it make sense?**

Yes it makes sense. Using the Cloudflare resolver over it's onion address gives you additional privacy and also makes the dns query tamper resistant.